# NodeJS - Is it possible to enable Profiler on demand and not through the `--prof` flag?

Tags: node.js

Sometimes it's necessary to collect runtime info, mainly in production. But [profiler](https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#--prof) have some overhead, so I don't want to enable it by default with the `--prof` flag but only when needed, for a short period.

Is it possible to enable it programmatically, by sending a signal to NodeJS process, similar like you enable the inspector with `kill -SIGUSR1`?

Answer (score 1):

I would imagine you can listen to SIGUSR2 like so...

```
// https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#signal-events
process.on('SIGUSR2', () => {
  console.log('SIGUSR2 signal received');


  const inspector = require('node:inspector');
  const fs = require('node:fs');
  const session = new inspector.Session();
  session.connect();

  // https://nodejs.org/api/inspector.html#cpu-profiler_1
  session.post('Profiler.enable', () => {
    session.post('Profiler.start', () => {
      // Invoke business logic under measurement here...

      // some time later...
      session.post('Profiler.stop', (err, { profile }) => {
        // Write profile to disk, upload, etc.
        if (!err) {
          fs.writeFileSync('./profile.cpuprofile', JSON.stringify(profile));
        }
      });
    });
}); 



});
```

Comment: Thanks, although it doesn't answer my original question of collecting raw JS runtime log, like what you get when you run with `--prof` flag